# How to pass complex class members to pytest parametrize decorator

Tags: python, class, pytest

I need to pass class members as parameters to `pytest.mark.parametrize`.
The following code does not work (I've used simple members strings, but in my case they are complex and constructed):

```
import pytest
class TestSmth(object):
     def setup_class(cls):
         cls.a = "a"
         cls.b = "b"
         cls.c = "c"

     @pytest.mark.parametrize("test_input,expected", [
     (self.a, "a"),
     (self.b, "b"),
     (self.c, "c")
     ])
     def test_members(test_input, expected):
         assert test_input == expected
```

Is it possible to achieve such result?
Or something similar?

Answer (score 2):

This code doesn't work because Python decorators [don't work that way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/341389/752976). It is unrelated to the actual data in the test parameters. If you were the one writing the decorator, you could [solve it by manually passing the instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14745223/python-member-function-decorators-use-instance-as-a-parameter), but this depends on the decorator itself doing the right thing.

As it stands, pytest decorators simply store the test data to be verified - and so you need to provide the data that's accessible by the time the desugared code is being ran, like so:

```
o = TestSmth()
o.setup_class()

@pytest.mark.parametrize("test_input,expected", [
(o.a, "a"),
(o.b, "b"),
(o.c, "c")
])
def test_members(test_input, expected):
    assert test_input == expected
```

I don't believe there are any inherent limitations to the data types being passed to those functions. If you still find that too limiting, pytest has a [substantial support](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/parametrize.html) for custom parametrization schemes. Without the details of your actual use (rather than a mock example), it's hard to tell what would fit the problem best.

Comment: I too have to pass some complex parameters for `test_input` and `expected` as in your example. One option is to just writing it out inside the arguments to parameterize.. or to define a Class, which contains the test_data. Is it best practice to define the test data in a class as OP pointed out?

Answer (score 1):

Found solution in pytest docs -> "Parametrizing test methods through per-class configuration¶"

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import pytest


def pytest_generate_tests(metafunc):
    # called once per each test function
    funcarglist = metafunc.cls.params[metafunc.function.__name__]
    argnames = sorted(funcarglist[0])
    metafunc.parametrize(argnames, [[funcargs[name] for name in argnames]
            for funcargs in funcarglist])

class Complex(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = "a"

class TestBase(object):
    A = Complex()
    params = {
        'test_a' : [dict (test_input=A)]
    }

    def test_a(self, test_input):
        assert test_input.a == "a"
```

It's ugly but it serves it's purpose.